# How to use an array variable instead of a range in a formula in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, reference

So, I want to use 1D and 2D arrays in place of the ranges in formulas, except that whatever I have tried has not worked. If anyone can, can they please help?

Also, when transposing my data, I don't understand how to do this by referencing other sheets.

```
Sub Testrun()

Cells(5, 6).Value = "=Sum([myArr])"

Set mcco = Workbooks("Book1.xlsb").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set mcfc = Workbooks("Book1.xlsb").Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set mcfb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsb").Worksheets("Sheet3")

TR = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))

FTNRowStart = 1
MainRowStart = 2
CVTRRowEnd = mcco.Range("A2", mcco.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1
FCRowEnd = mcfc.Range("A2", mcfc.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1

MNCol = 2
FNCol = 4
FTNCol = 8

CVTRmyArr = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(MainRowStart, MNCol), Cells(CVTRRowEnd, MNCol)))
FCmyArr = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(MainRowStart, MNCol), Cells(FCRowEnd, MNCol)))
FNmyArr = Application.Transpose(Range(Cells(MainRowStart, FNCol), Cells(FCRowEnd, FNCol)))

mcfc.Activate    

For i = 2 To TR
    s = 0
    TCJ = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 7
    For j = 8 To TCJ
        TCK = mcfb.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        For k = 2 To TCK
        XD = "=COUNTIFS(CVTRmyArr,'Sheet3'!R" & i & "C" & k & ",'Sheet3'!R[0]C" & k & ",FNmyArr,""*"" & SUBSTITUTE(MID(FNmyArr,FIND(""*"",SUBSTITUTE(FNmyArr,""("",""*"",LEN(FNmyArr) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(FNmyArr,""("","""")))) +1,LEN(FNmyArr)),"")"",""""))"

        mcfc.Cells(i, j).Value = XD
        s = s + Cells(i, j).Value
        Cells(i, j).Value = s

        Next k
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `Application.Transpose`? Do you mean `Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose`? And: to set a Range in a specific worksheet you may do like this: `Set r = Range(Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Sheets(2).Cells(3, 3))` (in your example could be something like `Range(mcco.Cells(MainRowStar, MNCol), mcco.Cells(CVTRRowEnd, MNCol))`

Comment: @WolfgangJacques `Application.Transpose`is weirdly enough valid, albeit it's not officially method of the `Application` object. I presume this is because vba automatically presumes it as a shorthand for `WorksheetFunction.Transpose`

Comment: @Rawrplus weird indeed. Seemlingly, there are differences in error handling: [link1](https://strugglingtoexcel.com/2018/02/09/worksheetfunction/) and [link2](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/24/the-worksheetfunction-method/)

Comment: Thank you so much! However the biggest problem I have is actually the countif function. I’m trying to (somehow) manage to assign all the values of a column into an array variable and then use that as the range in the COUNTIF formula. I tried searching on the internet but I still can’t find anyone who will explain it to me.

Comment: Don’t worry. Figured it out!